# How can I get field data for the current locale in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, localization

So I have a plugin with a service. Part of the service function is to grab a field (body) from an entry object that has been passed into the function.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_ExampleService extends BaseApplicationComponent {

    public function example($entry) {
        return $entry->body;
    }

}
```

The function will be called via Twig.

```
{{ craft.myPlugin.example(entry) }}
```

**How do I go about getting the field data for the users current locale?**

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close... You'll need to do this in a [Variable](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables), not a Service.

If your method already exists in a Service, or if you'll need to access it via PHP as well, then you can keep it in the Service. In that case, you'll still need a Variable method, but it can simply be a wrapper for your existing Service method.

Comment: I realized after posting this that your question is focused on _locales_. In theory, it should already be grabbing the value per the user's locale... is it not doing that?

Comment: Thanks Lindsey. Sorry, I should have been a little more detailed in my question. Yes, I've passed the function through a 'variable'. It's grabbing the locale version of the content I'm struggling with. I can't find anything that simply gets the content as per the current locale... and it's not doing it automatically.